# How can I group several git repositories into one repository

Tags: git, github, atom-editor

I'm attempting to create several Atom (the text editor) packages, and according to the distribution guidelines, each package has to have its own Github repository. I want to keep all my packages in one large repository on Github while still following the Atom package guidelines.

I've already looked into submodules, but I don't believe that they will help with what I want to accomplish.

If this is not doable, then how can I maintain one repository for all my Atom packages while still adhering to the Atom guidelines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Atom asks you to have one repository per package, there's little you can do about it.

Just as you have thought, you could use submodules:

- One repository per package.
- One *umbrella* repository whose only purpose is to hold all the other repositories as submodules, so that when you develop them, you have all grouped inside this main repository.

  - The only main thing you win is just having them grouped under this *umbrella*.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to group several git repositories is by repo tools. which used in Android development.You can reference the following page for details.
https://source.android.com/source/developing.html